# iOS: beacons detection taking a long time

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I have an app where I'm scanning for beacons ( I know the UIIDs) and displaying them. The first few times I ran it I found the beacons almost immediately. But now each time I run it, it seems to take longer and longer to detect them. Even though I have the beacons sitting on the desk right next to the device.

I've tried replacing the batteries, changing from a iPhone to an iPad, checking a beacon scanning app on the Mac, rebuilding the app, etc. I also have a range of different beacons from different manufacturers and they all seem to have the same issue. Nothing seems to fix this.

My code basically looks like this:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString:"61687109-905F-4436-91F8-E602F514C96D")!, identifier: "BlueCat beacon")
locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
```

And then I can wait for anything up to 5 or more minutes before any of the delegate methods get call.

This is the first time I've attempted to use beacons. Is this normal? Can it take a long time for a beacon to be seen by a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under ideal conditions, `didEnterRegion` callbacks on iOS come within a few seconds of a beacon coming into range.  Under less ideal conditions, these callbacks can take 15 minutes or more.

There are lots of things that can cause delays in detecting beacons when monitoring, and it's hard to say for sure without knowing exactly how you are testing.  Two tips:

1. **Hardware filter slots on iOS devices are limited** and are on a first-come, first-served basis.  If you have a bunch of beacon apps installed that have taken up these slots (or if your app has registered a bunch of regions), all these slots may have been taken up.  Once hardware filter slots are gone, detections fall back to software scans that happen about every 15 minutes.  Uninstall all apps (including yours) that may be holding on to these slots, then reinstall just your app.
2. **Make sure you aren't "in region" when you put the app to the background.**  If iOS believes it is in the region, you won't get a new `didEnterRegion` callback until after it realizes it left the region and then entered again.  The time for iOS to realize it exited the region is much longer than the time it takes to realize it entered.  To ensure it realizes it exited the region, you should always range for beacons when the app is in the foreground, and leave the app ranging in the foreground for about a minute to ensure iOS realizes it is no longer in region (it usually takes 30 seconds of ranging to trigger an exit.)  Only then should you put it in the background and turn on a beacon to measure detection times.